# Disable specific metric in Spring

Tags: spring, metrics

In Spring metrics I have bunch of following metrics:

```
response.auth.admin.realms.1ee065af2()":127.0
```

How to disable them by mask 'response' ?

Answer (score 0):

add line to your application.yml

```
management.metrics.enable.response: false
```

or properties file

```
management.metrics.enable.response=false
```

where *response* is prefix of metric which you want to switch off.